# How to add button in ActionBar(Android)?

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

I want to add a Button to the Action Bar to the right hand side of Example as in this screen shot:

[image: a screenshot of an actionbar with no buttons. the title is 'Example']

I get actionBar in onCreate method as:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and back button(onOptionsItemSelected method) as below:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    return true;
}
```

How can I add button?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

you have to create an entry inside `res/menu,`override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and inflate it

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.yourentry, menu);
    return true;
}
```

an entry for the menu could be:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/cart"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"/> 
</menu>
```

Comment: Ok.That works.But i dont understand use of orderInCategory and its value as 100.

Comment: It is an integer that represent the order of "importance" of the item, within a group. You can change it. As long as you have one or two elementes in the menu it does not make difference. you can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

Comment: Thank you.Now another question is that I add this menu in another activity but show different button instead of this.So how can i do that?

Comment: Oh,I understood that i have to create different file under res/menu to use different menu in another activity.By the way thank you.

Comment: Can we change the location of the button??
I'm getting it on extreme right. Can I have it in center??

Comment: But if I want to add `button` in `action bar` instead of `icon`,how should I write https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179217/xml-layout-look-weird-add-button-or-icon-in-action-bar

Answer (score 22):

An activity populates the ActionBar in its `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

Instead of using `setcustomview()`, just override `onCreateOptionsMenu` like this:

```
@Override    
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
  return true;
}
```

If an actions in the ActionBar is selected, the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method is called. It receives the selected action as parameter. Based on this information you code can decide what to do for example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuitem1:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      break;
    case R.id.menuitem2:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item 2 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      break;
  }
  return true;
}
```