# Can't add Button to Android ActionBar API 21

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I wanted to add a Search button to my Android ActionBar, to do this I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425742/how-to-add-button-in-actionbarandroid) answer. The only thing that happens is that the "Search" button is added to the menu itself and not the ActionBar (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot]

This is my search.java (The Activity to show the search button in):

```
public class search extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And this is my menu_search.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:title="search"
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/searchicon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Any help is apreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `The only thing that happens is that the "Search" button is added to the menu itself` because that is exactly what you did. there is no button being added to the action bar. if you want to add a button you should be using `Toolbar` and NOT `Actionbar`

Comment: @tyczj: Um, no, you can add action bar items to an action bar just fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have never seen a `Button` in an action bar i have seen `ActionButtons` which was not said by the OP

Comment: @tyczj: If you look at the code, the OP would appear to be seeking an action bar item. I agree that the title of the question is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `appcompat-v7`. You need to change your `android:showAsAction` attribute to an `app:showAsAction` attribute, with a definition for the `app` namespace (`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`).

This will give you something like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:title="search"
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/searchicon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Also, you probably do not need `android:orderInCategory`.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```