# Add buttons to the Activity Bar

Tags: java, android

I would like to know , how to add custom buttons to the activitybar and set OnClick method to it? If someone know the answer, can he/she please post it to me...

Like this:

[image]

Comment: use tool bar, you can customize it as much as you want.

Comment: first google answer: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

Comment: see this link too http://stackoverflow.com/a/35405244/3788166

Comment: you can check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425742/how-to-add-button-in-actionbarandroid , it's the same question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create a menu xml resource, like this (let's call it example_menu.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/one"
        android:title="actione one"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/two"
        android:title="actione two"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

then in your activity, add this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

if you want your items to always be visible as icons, just change app:showAsAction="ifRoom" to app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: But how to add a action (onclick method) to that?

Comment: I should do what...?

Comment: You should do something like this: http://pastebin.com/f5BUAVDG

Comment: I mean i need a button to the activity bar that like has OnClick Method and that link doesnt help me at all...

Comment: Of course it is. The function I gave you is called when one of the menu items is clicked. I'm using switch-case to determine which button was clicked. In the xml I gave you above I gave id's to the items. Then in the function that I put on pastebin.com I check which of the id's in the xml belong to the item that was pressed.

Comment: Oh... I didnt realize that.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should read through [**this**](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar), and as mentioned before, use toolbar. This way adding a Button becomes way more easy.