# How to create button in Action bar in android

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-actionbar

I am working on android application where i need a button in action bar.
These are my activity and java files.
So, i need a button at right side of my tool bar.
Thanks in advance.

**content_b2_bdeliveries.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.ideabiz.riderapplication.ui.B2BDeliveriesActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_b2_bdeliveries">
//remaining code;
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_b2_bdeliveries.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.ideabiz.riderapplication.ui.B2BDeliveriesActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_b2_bdeliveries" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**B2BDeliveriesActivity.java:**

```
public class B2BDeliveriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String TAG_NAME="B2BActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b2_bdeliveries);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //Log.d(TAG_NAME,actionBar.toString());
    if (actionBar != null) {
        try {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
                Log.d(TAG_NAME, "Null Pointer from setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled" + e.getMessage());
                Utilities.issueTokenUpload("Null Pointer from setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled" + e, sharedPreferences.getInt("tripId", 999999), sharedPreferences.getString("driverPhoneNo", "9999999999"), sharedPreferences.getString("driverName", "default"), getResources().getString(R.string.version));
            }
    }
}
```

[image: sample requirement picture]

Comment: i have used  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        finish();

        return true;

    }      in my B2BDeliveriesActivity.java page

Comment: what do you mean by button? menu buttons?

Comment: HI Ashish, i need a single button on my right side of tool bar

Comment: dear you can add menu file and add there item

Comment: how to perform onclick function() then?

Comment: ActionBar is like any other layout meaning you can add a button inside that action bar in xml

Answer (score 95):

In your activity class, override the following methods if they are not there by default:

```
// create an action bar button
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // R.menu.mymenu is a reference to an xml file named mymenu.xml which should be inside your res/menu directory. 
    // If you don't have res/menu, just create a directory named "menu" inside res
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// handle button activities
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.mybutton) {
    // do something here
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

mymenu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/mybuttonicon"
    />
</menu>
```

Comment: Hi Onur, where i have to use your mymenu.xml code in content.xml or activity.xml?

Comment: just create a new folder in your res folder called menu  (if it doesn't already exists)  and add a new file called menu.xml

Comment: Same code I have used but it didn't work. I don't know why this answer is upvoted

Comment: @RohitSawai Well, is it possible that you had a mistake of some sort? I suggest you post your code and the error so that you don't mislead other people reading this answer. The reason you don't know why this answer is upvoted may be that you don't know how to execute it properly, not that the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to customize UI of your ActionBar, then you can use Toolbar as ActionBar. Here are the steps to do the same :

1. Add below code as a child of AppBarLayout in your activity layout xml.

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" >

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:weightSum="1">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/title"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:text="ActionBar Title"/>

               <Button
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           </LinearLayout>

       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   ```
2. Make your Toolbar as ActionBar by adding the below code in your Activity onCreate() method.

   ```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   ```
3. In AndroidManifest.xml, add following theme to your activity:

   ```
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
   ```
4. In styles.xml add following code:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Here are the steps to get it done:

1. Create a menu in res/menu (Name it my_menu.xml)

   ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_cart"
       android:icon="@drawable/cart"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
       android:showAsAction="always"/> 
   </menu>
   ```
2. Override onCreateOptionsMenu and inflate the menu

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
   return true;
   }
   ```

Visit: [How to add button in ActionBar(Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425742/how-to-add-button-in-actionbarandroid)

Answer (score 3):

Make a xml file for your menu in `res/menu` directory ( `menu_main.xml` in this case):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.rashish.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Button title"
        android:icon="@drawable/buttonicon"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

then add these methods in your activity class :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //process your onClick here
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

its described properly at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml . You can create a menu.xml file at "menu" directory, which is at the same level as "drawable" and "layout" directories