# xml layout look weird (Add button or icon in action bar)

Tags: android, xml, button, android-actionbar

I want to add a save `button` in action bar but it shows below the `action bar`.

What is the correct to solve ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/save"
                android:text="SAVE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background = "@drawable/img_receipt"
        android:src="@drawable/upload"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:id="@+id/image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Add a description"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
         />

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:paddingBottom="75dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:hint="Add a description"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_edittext"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

As you can see the save button is placed below action bar. I want it place beside the healthy app title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get it works

In my **Receipt** Activity, add these two lines

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and add this lines in **androidMainFest** to avoid the app cras

```
<activity android:name=".Receipt"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add button on action bar like that...

1. Remove toolbar(if you are using only to add save button on action bar)
2. create the menu_main xml file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <item
   android:id="@+id/action_save"
   android:icon="@drawable/you_resourse_here"
   android:title="Save"
   app:showAsAction="always"
   android:orderInCategory="0"/>

   </menu>
   ```
3. Then in your activity, if you created a new file your need to edit onCreateOptionsMenu

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
   return true;
   }
   ```
4. and you can edit what the actions do in the following method:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
   // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
   // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
   int id = item.getItemId();


   if (id == R.id.action_save) {
      do something when you click on save button
    return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
   ```

   Hope this will help you.

Comment: But I want to have a `button` on action bar, not any icon

Comment: you can use a img for button like..android:icon="@drawable/you_resourse_here"..and it will look like a button and also works as a button

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Initially, make an XML file inside your layout folder say "toolbar.xml"

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/lightblue"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


// And inside any layout file where you want to use toolbar jsut do       following

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.limatrder.activitis.Bill_details">

 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgback_billDetail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/action_bar_cross" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtviewcart_billdetais"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="View Cart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


<!-- here you can write your code for remaining design-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout"
            android:background="@color/lightblue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


// and in yor style.xml use 

Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```